# Recursion with the least sideeffect

Tags: c#, recursion, side-effects

So I have a tree of people with children and I only want to get the people with cars. if a child has a car but the parent does not, I want to keep the parent in the tree.

I thought the best way would be to use a recursive function, that looked like this:

```
private Person CheckPerson(Person person)
{
    List<Person> removeList = new List<Person>();

    foreach (Person child in Person.Children)
    {
        if (CheckPerson(child) == null)
        {
            // I can't remove the children here because
            // they are used in the foreach loop
            removeList.Add(child);
        }

    }

    foreach (Person removable in removeList)
    {
        Person.Children.Remove(removable);
    }

    if (person.Children.Count() > 0)
    {
        return person;
    }
    else if (person.cars.Count() > 0)
    {
        return person;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but this way I do change the parameter person, I remove his children.

The other ways I tried are as below.

- return void
- return bool
- ref parameter

I also tried doing it without a return value and just looking back at the input person for the result, but this didn't save the changes.

Returning a bool to determine if a child should be removed worked, but the original method call did not have any use for the bool. So the method had side effects since Person -> bool, but I still changed the person

using a ref parameter I wasn't able to compile because I remove the children and there for changing the object in my foreach loop.

So I'm wondering what the best way would be to use a recursive method with the least side effects, or what the best practice would be?

Comment: What if a Child's Child has a car? Do you keep all the parents? Or just the first level one?

Comment: start from the leaves and work up, as soon as you find a car include the branch.

Comment: @Thomas I want to navigate from the root of the tree(so the oldest grandparent) to all the people with cars. So I need every step inbetween to keep the tree structure alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need a Test whether a car is available you could use this:

```
public Person CheckPerson(Person person)
{
    return person.Cars.Any() || person.Children.Any(x => CheckPerson(x) != null) ? person : null;                    
}
```

But I think you should return an `IEnumerable<Person>` that contains all persons that have a car (or one child has a car).

Maybe is could look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonsWithCars(Person person)
{
    var personReturned = false;
    if (person.Cars.Any())
    {
        yield return person;
        personReturned = true;
    }

    foreach (var child in person.Children)
    {
         foreach (var item in GetPersonsWithCars(child))
         {
             if (!personReturned)
             {
                 yield return person;
                 personReturned = true;
             }

             yield return item;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: ??? No. But the ?: operator will return it... `.Any()` is exactly the same like `.Count() > 0` but without iterating over all items to get the real count. It only tests if there is an item or not.

Comment: In the bottom example, wouldn't the tree structure go away?

I tried the top example and it works perfectly, but I'm not sure how it works.
why are the children without cars removed?(I want this but don't quite understand it)

Comment: Yes you'll lose the tree structure. The second example iterates over all items and returns all that has a car in the sub tree. You'll get a plane "list" of all items instead of a tree but in most cases you'll perform an action for each item that matches your condition. In that case you don't need to know how to traverse the tree. You'll get all items lazy in a simple Enumerable. It depends on your needs if you prefer the first or second example.